# ExpandableListView get the parent of group position from View(child)

Tags: java, android, onclick, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i am looking for hours and trying to understand why is the event "onChildClick" is not called when i press the child.
by the way "IsChildSelectable" is "true" in the adapter.

here is my code:

public class Graphic_Planner extends Activity {

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphic__planner);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
            listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
          @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```